# JQuery Mobile Button - Absolute position FROM center?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create something in JQuery Mobile, however I need to be able to position a button from the center. Right now, the button is positioned from the top-left corner, and as such if I resize the window, everything is horribly off-center.

```
<body>
    <button>Button</button>
    <div />
</body>

div {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: black;
}

button {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chpt3x1v/4/
I couldn't get JQM working in JSFiddle (didn't know how without it showing loads of errors), so I just used a regular button, but the same premise applies.

TWO IMAGES:
[image: Without Ripple enabled]
[image: With Ripple enabled]
As you can see, it is completely off-center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

You need to give the button a set width and height, and then set the top margin to negative one half the height, and the left margin to negative half the width:

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/chpt3x1v/6/)**

```
<div class="thediv"></div>        
<button data-role="none" class="theButton">Button</button>

.thediv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.theButton {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You can use fixed positioning and a negative margin to keep it centered:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="centered"><button>Button</button></div>
    </div> 
</div>  

.centered {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.centered button {
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chpt3x1v/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this wasn't my question. I want to keep it absolutely positioned at a certain coordinate FROM the center. Not TO the center, so I want the center of the button to be where the coordinates point to. Maybe I haven't explained it well enough in the OP. Maybe if I make the button bigger, it will illustrate my point better.

Comment: @RealFighter64, ok, see updated answer and jsFiddle. Negative margins with specified height and width is the trick.

Comment: A question; to make the page scalable to different devices, I need to use percentage widths and heights, would this work with that?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code doesn't have an opening  tag. Secondly, you need to have the parent element, i.e. the div, positioned as relative.

Third, you've positioned your button to the very edge of the div by using the same dimensions. Try:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <button>Button</button>
    <div />
</body>

div {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: black;
}

button {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

The z-index property will allow the button to overlay the div.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this was not my question. I'm only using the div as a placement guide, to show my point. If I put the button as 200px, 200px, it is placed there from the top-left corner, while I want it to be placed from the center. Also, it might also help to make the button larger to illustrate it better.

Comment: This is a little confusing, firstly why would you need to use a div as a placement guide in this particular example? Why not just use absolute positioning on the button?

Comment: The reason I have the div there is because it shows where the button is placed relative to the specified coordinates, which, as shown on the OP, is too far to the bottom-right. I want the CENTRE of the button to be placed on the corner of the div, NOT the top-left corner. The corner of the div is just to show the coords that the button should appear on.

Comment: In that case using your original CSS, take 50% of the button width away from your horizontal positioning